# WP_Query, ACF field and array

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

First of all, sorry this title, I really don't know how title the question without write a blobtext! :)

Anyway, my problem is this one: I have a custom post "Risorse" (en: Resources). It supports only titles, all other parameters are custom fields created with ACF. One of these is a relationship where I can select one or more pages.
So, for example I can create a Resource and select a relationship with two pages. In DB it is saved in this way

```
a:2:{i:0;s:3:"727";i:1;s:3:"729";}
```

Now, when I load for example the page 727, I want to list all Resources that have a relation with that page.

I'm trying a custom query but I don't know how set the meta_query array. I tried something like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'product',
        'value' => get_the_id(),
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
```

Obviously no posts are returned because the meta_key 'product' contains an array of values.
How can I get all Resources the have a relation with a specific post?

Comment: OK, I solved in this way:   

`'meta_query' => array(  
    array(  
        'key' => 'product',  
        'value' => '"'.get_the_id().'"',  
        'compare' => 'LIKE'  
    )  
)`

Comment: Go ahead and add your comment as the answer, and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved in this way:

```
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'product',
    'value' => '"'.get_the_id().'"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  )
)
```